# Guice service dependencies

Tags: java, guice

I have three guava `Service`s which get started by a guava `ServiceManager` asynchronously.

The first service is the database connection pool which needs to start fully before the second/third service can successfully process incoming messages. Obviously with these being started asynchronously, the database may not have fully started before the second/third service starts to process a message, which will lead to exceptions.

What is the desired pattern here?

I can inject the database service into the other services and call the `awaitRunning()` method in the service startup, but then I will suffer the same issue when the `ServiceManager` is shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I believe guice does not have an out-of-the-box mechanism for this. Spring e.g. has a depends-on attribute that can define some ordering. There are frameworks that give you this with guice as well (e.g. dropwizard guicey implements an order annotation). This is however fairly simple to solve.

The approach is to use multibindings to define a manager for all dependency classes. This I will call Managed (adopted from jetty). The interface will implement an ordering. We then use a manager that starts all the services one by one in a well defined order (can also be used for shutdown if wanted).

See my code example here:

```
public class ExecutionOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Injector createInjector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                Multibinder<Managed> multiBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Managed.class);
                multiBinder.addBinding().to(Service1.class);
                multiBinder.addBinding().to(Service2.class);

                bind(ManagedManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });

        createInjector.getInstance(ManagedManager.class); // start it
    }

    public interface Managed extends Comparable<Managed> {

        public default void start() {}
        public default int getOrder() { return 0;}

        @Override
        default int compareTo(Managed o) {
            return Integer.compare(getOrder(), o.getOrder());
        }
    }

    public static class ManagedManager {
        @Inject
        public ManagedManager(final Set<Managed> managed) {
            managed.stream().sorted().forEach(Managed::start);
        }

    }

    public static class Service1 implements Managed {

        @Override
        public void start() {
            System.out.println("Started Service 1");
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public static class Service2 implements Managed {

        @Override
        public void start() {
            System.out.println("Started Service 2");
        }

        @Override
        public int getOrder() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

My - admittedly stupidly named - ManagedManager is injected by guice with all Managed interfaces, using guice's multibindings (see the module I initialise).  I then sort that and call start.

The start method would be where you initialise your services (e.g. your database connection). By overwriting the getOrder() method you can define which service is started at which point.

That way you get a well defined startup behaviour and you can adapt the interface to have a well defined shutdown behaviour as well.

I hope this helps,

Artur